# Rename {msword} to {ms-word}, or create generic {ms-office} tag to cover Office-related questions

Tags: discussion, tagging

This stems from the inappropriately tagged question [Is it possible to put MS Excel graphs into a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88449/5764)

I don't know whether creating a separate [ms-excel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-excel) would be of use, hence the generic (master) [ms-office](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) suggestion, with synonyms [ms-word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) and [ms-excel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-excel).

Comment: +1; I'm in favor of two separate tags [tag:ms-word] and [tag:ms-excel].

Comment: I did not search for, but perhaps also `{ms-powerpoint}` would be useful?

Comment: Must the tags be Microsoft-specific? What works with Excel most likely also works with Open-/LibreOffice.

Comment: Just a note: tag [tag:msword] is currently used 57 times. This includes: 20 closed questions and 1 question about MS Excel. I don't think it is worth having another tag.

Comment: Why don't we make tags for file-formats instead of products?

Answer (score 15):

Questions about Excel have typically nothing to do with Word, and vice-versa; hence, I'm in favor of two separate tags [ms-word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) and [ms-excel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-excel).

Comment: Ideally I would go for this option; being as specific as possible. It avoids future re-tagging when a generic tag becomes too vague (perhaps similar to [tag:tikz-pgf]). It's always easier reverting back to a more generic tag (say [tag:ms-office]) than it is the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

The cases, where other MS Office product than MS Word is in question, are really rare. Therefore I don't see the necessity of more tags. I suggest having [ms-office](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) with [ms-word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) as a synonym. This synonym for users who try to put `word` in and who need to get the right tag suggested.

Comment: Why not more generic? We could have {office} with {ms-office}, {ms-word}, {ms-excel}, {ms-powerpoint}, {openoffice} and {libreoffice} as synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

I have edited two tag wikis on Excel ([excel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel)) and Powerpoint ([powerpoint]), both of which of course are Office products. I think it would make sense to be consistent so if Word is called msword/ms-word then perhaps we need a change to ms-excel or ms-powerpoint as well. Or, vice versa. Powerpoint questions are not uncommon in association with Beamer questions and there seems to be a few on Excel when it comes to moving data from one to the other. I would be in favour of dropping the MS-Office tag since it is so general that I cannpt see how the entire MS-Office package (which includes much more than just Word/Excel/Powerpoint) would tie in with (La)TeX.

Comment: a possible problem with getting rid of the "ms" prefix entirely is that "word" is, well, an ordinary word that one might want to search for.  (not by itself, but i could conceive of someone wanting to search for "multi word string".)  "excel" and "powerpoint" are distinctly product names, so it would be exceedingly rare for someone to be deluged with irrelevant responses.  i realize this isn't exactly what you propose, but wanted to make the point.

Comment: I totally agree about "word", it would be quite a poor tag without the "ms". I was trying to push for thinking about systematic tags. For OpenOffice (LibreOffice) we have a tag with the same name but nothing on the different components such as "Writer" and calc". A quick search-and-look indicates that these "Offices" tags are synonymous to their wordprocesors. But, as long as we know what we are talking about, all is well.