# Rename tag msword to ms-word

Tags: feature-request, tagging

Currently the msword tag has over 120 questions in it.  The tag dealing with Microsoft Word on Stack Overflow is called ms-word; for the sake of cross-site consistency, I propose that we change the name used in this tag (creating the obvious synonym) for this site.

Having tags ms-word and ms-excel was the most popular option in the two-year-old discussion, [Rename {msword} to {ms-word}, or create generic {ms-office} tag to cover Office-related questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3132/rename-msword-to-ms-word-or-create-generic-ms-office-tag-to-cover-office), although the issue of what to do with the questions already tagged msword was not addressed in that discussion.

Comment: I'm more familiar with `msword` than `ms-word` independently of the tags here, so from my point of view, I'd almost certainly write the synonym rather than the tag name, in this case. But I don't know that matters. Does it make much difference whether one is a synonym of the other or the other is a synonym of the one? (Real question: I have no idea.)

Comment: @cfr - It makes a difference to people who are following tags using tag filters; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105667/tag-synonym-filtering